# mdtheorem is only framing the bottom-half of my text

Tags: mdframed

I'm using the `mdtheorem` environment and for some reason the boxes seem to not print out correctly when I compile and open my pdf file. Everything compiles fine, but I get that my theorem is only framed on the bottom-right, and the top-left part of the frame is missing.

I just use a command like, say,

```
\begin{algo} \label{alg:ew} \textbf{Calcul }
\end{algo}
```

any ideas?

---

Ok, well, this is an example of code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


%\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}

\newmdtheoremenv{alg}{Algorithme}


\begin{document}


\begin{alg}  \ \ \textbf{Graphiques de $P(X=x)$ et $P(X\leq x)$ }
\end{alg}

\end{document}
```

Which is just the basic use of it here. I was able to make the whole box appear now, but only when I was zoomed in so close on the thing I couldn't see anything else.

Is there a way to make the frame thicker, so maybe that would help the frame to post properly even when not so zoomed in?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem; we cannot guess how you are defining your environment!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Sometimes it depends on the zooming or something like this of your pdf viewer.

Comment: You can say `\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1pt]{alg}{Algorithme}`, but the result won't be nice. In general, the thicker the line, the more funerary the result.

Comment: Your example looks correct in SumatraPDF and PDF-Xchange viewer. Viewer from Texworks doesn't show left border and adobe reader doesn't show top border.

Comment: an answer posted below identifies this question as containing a possible answer: [mdframed missing half the frame](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124539/579)

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that frame was not beign displayed due to the thickness of the frame line, you can adjust the line width with `\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=<size>]{alg}{Algorithme}`

Here is the result with `[linewidth=2.0pt]`:

[image]

Of course you can also include other options as well. So `[linewidth=2.0pt,linecolor=red]` yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}

\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=2.0pt]{alg}{Algorithme}


\begin{document}
\begin{alg}  \ \ \textbf{Graphiques de $P(X=x)$ et $P(X\leq x)$ }
\end{alg}
\end{document}
```