# Tabular with horizontal and vertical double line, avoid ugly corner

Tags: tables

I am using tabular to make simple table, I want to have double line on the sides. The problem is that the double-lines do not meet elegantly at the bottom-right corner:

[image: badcorner]

How can I make the double lines meet in a better what (e.g. forming an double ell shape)?

Other environments and packages are welcomed but `tabular` is preferred.

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c||}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Vertical rules in tabular material are *always* ugly and distracting. Have a look at [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). This package gives you some useful macros and some hints on nice looking tables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by Johannes, vertical rules should be avoided. You should use the package [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to create nice tables.

However David Carlisle created the package [`hhline`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hhline) which supports such requests.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array,hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c||}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
 \hhline{=:=:b|}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! :) :P :/ . Do you know why the lines are rendered with some irregularities (as if they were superimposed)?

Comment: @alfC: Normally this is related to your viewer. Heiko Oberdiek explained this issue related to another package: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124539/mdframed-missing-half-the-frame/124562#124562