# Border in PDF not always visible (depending on zoom), mdframe

Tags: mdframed

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


%Definitionsumgebung
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdtheoremenv{mydef}{Definition}


\begin{document}

\begin{mydef}
Im Interview stellt der Requirements-Engineer einem oder mehreren Stakeholdern vorgegebene Fragen und protokolliert deren Antworten. Weiter im Gespräch auftretende Fragen können sofort geklärt werden. Der Requirements-Engineer hat dadurch die Möglichkeit, auch neue Anforderungen zu erkennen oder implizite Anforderungen aufzudecken.
\end{mydef}

\end{document}
```

When I view the resulting pdf the border is not always completely visbible. If I zoom at 300% its showing correctly.

Since I'm currently writing my thesis it should be correct because I also hand in the PDF File.

[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: `\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}` seems to solve the problem.

Comment: It's because of your PDF viewer: depending on the zoom, it will aggregate pixels in a way that sometimes makes thin lines "disappear". But if they a present when you zoom a lot, they *are* here and will be printed. (PS: I found no issue with the code of your MWE)

Answer (score 1):

I tried different solutions and the only change that (kind of) worked for me is to set a different border width. Use the `linewidth` attribute, as in the following example:

```
\mdfsetup{
    linewidth=0.6pt
}

\begin{mdframed}
...
\end{mdframed}
```

The full example can be found in another question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391855/143643).