# Continuing solution frame for exams

Tags: macros, boxes, mdframed, framed, exam

**New edit:** The proposed answer by magula, which used to work with version `2.5` of `exam.cls` no longer works with the current version `2.603`. The following was included as a note for version `2.601`: "We changed command and environment names in the code from framed.sty that's included (slightly modified) in exam.cls so that the user can say \usepackage{framed} without creating conflicts.  This also allows the user to use packages, such as minted.sty, that load framed.sty." I'm not sure if the changes made now render the current given answer/hack useless, but it simply deosn't work anymore.

**Question:** Can `TheSolution` environment be renewed in such a way that the framed box provided for the solution does not break into separate boxes on different pages as also illustrated in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13506/43245).

The code

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\def\MakeFramed#1{\begin{mdframed}}
\def\endMakeFramed{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question A short question.
\begin{solution}
A short solution.
\end{solution}

\question A question with a long solution.

\begin{solution}
The long solution continues onto another page: \lipsum[1-8]
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

produces a page break that looks like

[image]

instead of the following desired look:

[image]

In [the manual](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf), on page 74, it mentions that one could use `\renewenvironment` to completely customize the solution environment by changing the definition of `TheSolution`. My question is how I could do this to make the frame extend onto the next page in the desired way indicated above and the linked to question at the beginning of this question.

Comment: @AGoldMan I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 if that helps. Also, I assume you have the latest version of `exam.cls` installed? It was rather recently updated. It could very easily have something to do with my distribution I suppose, but I find that odd.

Comment: Apologies, didn't realize I had an old version. New solution is up.

Comment: @AGoldMan Ah, yes, that would explain it--still have a problem concerning vertical spacing between questions and solution boxes though. It shrinks drastically with the proposed modification.

Comment: Give me some more time, i'll give you a nicer implementation

Comment: @AGoldMan The spacing is fine now, I think. Is that what you were referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new version, the commands you need to change to remimplement the original solution are `exam@MakeFramed` and `endexam@MakeFramed`

So you should change

```
\def\MakeFramed#1{\begin{mdframed}}
\def\endMakeFramed{\end{mdframed}}
```

to

```
\makeatletter
\def\exam@MakeFramed#1{\begin{mdframed}}
\def\endexam@MakeFramed{\end{mdframed}}
\makeatother
```

This is a classic example of namespacing in TeX, where private macros have their name prefixed with the name of the package they belong to.

Comment: Oh how infuriating! But also encouraging...I read through the `exam.cls` code and tried exactly what you provided in your answer, *but* I forgot the all important `\makeatletter` and `makeatother` commands. `:(` I mean hey...I'm learning from this though! Also useful for anyone else who stumbles across this answer...the frames look a little messed up when viewed zoomed out in Adobe, but `\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}` fixes this as noted in Heiko's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124562/43245). Thanks for the answer and impressing upon me the need to remember `make...`

Answer (score 5):

Just redefining `TheSolution` environment to be `mdframed` seems to work.  You can add the heading "Solution:" and provide extra vertical spacing to match the original style too:

[image: Sample output]

with page breaks like

[image: Sample break]

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\renewenvironment{TheSolution}{\begin{mdframed}[skipabove=\baselineskip,innertopmargin=\baselineskip,innerbottommargin=\baselineskip]
  \textbf{Solution:}\enspace\ignorespaces}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question A short question.
\begin{solution}
A short solution.
\end{solution}

\question A question with a long solution.

\begin{solution}
The long solution continues onto another page: \lipsum[1-8]
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have now added some code to adjust the styling.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! It's nice to know another approach for going about fixing this perceived problem. (At least I don't think multiple boxes across several pages is good.) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage{mdframed}

\def\MakeFramed#1{\begin{mdframed}}
\def\endMakeFramed{\end{mdframed}}
```

This simply replaces the commands TheSolution uses at start and end of the content with the mdframed ones.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124539/mdframed-missing-half-the-frame.
Using \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} doesn't remove the problem, but might make it lesser. If that's fine, you could also try just making the lines thicker. (e.g. `\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=1pt]`). Both together should render a good result.

Comment: You could also try to find out how fbox draws the lines and why that doesn't render this problem.

Comment: Months ago I see a setting in Acrobat Reader that changes the width of thin lines. Another solution might be to use wider lines for the frames. The same thing happens with tables rules.